# The seed entity for entity type 'CustomDataType' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'SoftwareVersionVersion'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, seeding

I'm fairly new to EF Core but I am trying to seed a database using EF Core 6 and I am getting the following error when trying to create a migration.

> The seed entity for entity type 'CustomDataType' cannot be added
> because no value was provided for the required property
> 'SoftwareVersionVersion'.

I have a BaseEntity class which most other entity classes inherit from that looks like this:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SoftwareVersion SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
}
```

I think the issue may have something to do with the fact that my SoftwareVersion class contains a single column of type string which acts as the primary key:

```
public class SoftwareVersion
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public SoftwareVersion() 
    {
        this.Version = "1.0.0";
    }
}
```

Here is my CustomDataType class:

```
public class CustomDataType : BaseEntity
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have been following the documentation to seed my database using the modelBuilder in the OnModelCreating method of my context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Seed();
}

public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SoftwareVersion>().HasData(SoftwareVersionSeedData());
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomDataType>().HasData(CustomDataTypeSeedData());
}

public SoftwareVersion[] SoftwareVersionSeedData()
{
    return new[]
    {
         new SoftwareVersion { Version = "1.0.0" }
    };
}

public static CustomDataType[] CustomDataTypeSeedData()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new CustomDataType { Id = 1, Code = 1000001, Description = "Binary" },
        new CustomDataType { Id = 2, Code = 1000002, Description = "Datetime" },
        new CustomDataType { Id = 3, Code = 1000003, Description = "Integer" },
        new CustomDataType { Id = 4, Code = 1000004, Description = "Other" },
        new CustomDataType { Id = 5, Code = 1000005, Description = "String" },
        new CustomDataType { Id = 6, Code = 1000006, Description = "Boolean" },
    };
}
```

Running a migration with my seed data in the current state obviously causes an error because I am not defining a SoftwareVersion in the CustomDataTypeSeedData method but even when I use the following pattern I am still getting the same error:

```
new CustomDataType { Id = 1, Code = 1000001, Description = "Binary", SoftwareVersion = new SoftwareVersion() },
```

I'm just not sure where exactly I'm going wrong or, indeed, if there is a better way to fix this.  The only way I've found to get around the error when creating a migration is to make my SoftwareVersion nullable in my BaseEntity but this is not ideal as the SoftwareVersion is a required field.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent the above error by marking my SoftwareVersion as virtual and adding a separate property for the SoftwareVersionId in my BaseEntity class:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SoftwareVersionId { get; set; }
    public virtual SoftwareVersion SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
}
```

So my seed data method now looks like this:

```
public static CustomDataType[] CustomDataTypeSeedData()
{
    return new[]
    {
        new CustomDataType { Id = 1, Code = 1000001, Description = "Binary", SoftwareVersionId = "1.0.0" }
        // etc 
        // etc
    };
}
```